# Скачивание файлов

Tags: c#, .net, download

Здравствуйте, проблема заключается в следующем: мне необходимо программно скачать текстовый файл с сервера(https://vk.com/doc124526200_459995988).[image: содержание файла]

Для этого я использую следующий код:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://vk.com/doc124526200_459995988"), "http.txt");
```

Однако, сохраненный файл является пустым:
[image: Сохраненный файл]
В чём может быть проблема и как её решить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том что вы используете асинхронную версию функции `DownloadFileAsync` без `await`.

Самое простое решение, заменить на

```
client.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://vk.com/doc124526200_459995988"), "http.txt");
```

Другое решение сделать

```
await client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://vk.com/doc124526200_459995988"), "http.txt");
```

При этом функция с этим кодом должна быть объявлена с модификатором `async`

Почитать про `async/await` можно тут - [Асинхронные методы, async и await.](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.3.php)

Comment: пробовал заменить на DownloadFile - в результате в файл сохраняется html-код страницы :/

Comment: @Алексей видимо туда и ведёт ссылка. В этом случае рекомендую спарсить сначала её, потом из неё извлечь уже реальный путь к файлу и потом уже его скачивать.

Comment: @Алексей просто этот адрес ведёт не на сам файл а на html страничку  где внутри неё где-то есть ссылка для скачивания уже самого файла.

Comment: Мне не принципиально качать именно этот файл, просто нужно было проверить работоспособность кода. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: И я все еще нуждаюсь в прямой ссылке на файл, у Вас случайно какой-нибудь не завалялось?)

Comment: @Алексей Если ответ вам подошёл, отметьте его.

Comment: @Алексей можете на этом проверить  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/robots.txt

Comment: просто хочу проверить, будет ли работать обычный Download и правда ли дело просто в ссылке)
Я пробовал качать файлы с гугл-диска - результат тот же самый

Comment: выше дал ссылку на файл для проверки

Comment: @Алексей на гугл диске и на яндекс диске файлы тоже не напрямую лежат а в обёртке страницы HTML

Comment: Есть контакт) Большое спасибо за уделённое Вами время.

Comment: @Алексей Пожалуйста