# github.com. Как скачать последнюю версию проекта на локальный диск?

Tags: c#, github, octokit.net

Я обычно скачиваю проект по ссылке (см. Снимок экрана)
Как программно и сохранять на локальный диск с помощью octokit.net:
 - сохранить в формате «zip»?
 - или в распакованном формате?

Когда наводим мышку на кнопку "Download ZIP" браузер подсказывает, что файл этот лежит по адресу https://github.com/Ryozuki/HelperBot/archive/master.zip.
Вопрос стоит в том чтобы решение именно получало эту ссылку, а не формировало 
 по принципу

```
var url = "https://github.com/" + textBox2.Text + "/" + textBox3.Text + "/archive/master.zip";
```

Т.к. раньше я сталкивался с ссылками у которых на конце не "master.zip", а номер релиза (по моему)...
Сейчас эти проекты найти не могу, но это было

Пробую использовать код, но создаёт пустой архив «*.zip»

```
  var latestAsset = await client.Repository.Get("Ryozuki", "HelperBot");

        //Download Release.zip here
        var response = await client.Connection.Get<object>(new Uri(latestAsset.Url), new Dictionary<string, string>(), null);

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.HttpResponse.Body.ToString()); ;
        File.WriteAllBytes("RyozukiHelperBot.zip", bytes);
```

Ссылка на репозитарий - https://github.com/Ryozuki/HelperBot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если Вам надо то, что на картинке, то это вроде [Get archive link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link) метод. Вы пытаетесь использовать [List releases](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) (то есть вы пытаетесь скачать то, что на скрине у вас в центре, `57 releases`, скомпилированный уже проект). Если вам нужны все же релизы, то пример вроде есть в [документации](https://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/).

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:NataliaTepluhina/vue-storefront.git` используйте же bash!!!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не могли бы вы более подробно описать... и показать пример кода...

А, то я что-то начитался уже... голова кругом... 
Попробовал несколько вариантов кода и все работают с какими-то косяками...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ И как быть если число релизов "0"?

Comment: Какая жесть, это для Юнити?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не... просто нужна кнопка(метод)...

Comment: У вас на картинке скачивание исходников, а в коде работа с релизами. Вы определитесь, чего хотите то

Comment: @tym32167 Если я правильно понял, то в "исходниках" всегда более обновлённое приложение(код), поэтому хотелось чтобы код скачивал "исходники". Скорректировал код, на сколько хватает опыта. PS. Буду признателен за помощь

Comment: вы когда мышку на кнопку "Download ZIP" наводите, вам браузер подсказывает, что файл этот лежит по адресу `https://github.com/Ryozuki/HelperBot/archive/master.zip`, оттуда его и качайте

Comment: @tym32167 Изменил вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/888403/revisions . Не могли бы вы подсказать на примере кода как это сделать с помощью `octokit.net` или без него или другими способами... Прошу извинить если вопрос элементарный, но уже перебрал кучу вариантов и все полурабочие....

Comment: ну, url я вам уже дал, как скачать глядите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781767/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: `но уже перебрал кучу вариантов и все полурабочие` - все, что пытаетесь, добавляйте в вопрос